# UITableView custom reordering crash

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, custom-controls, user-experience

I’m working on a concept which enables user to “fling” cells in the process of reordering the UITableView (you can have a look at the short demo on [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FV4HN8kdoJk) and clone my repo from [Github](https://github.com/Czajnikowski/FlingUX.git)) and I have a problem, cause my app crashes… Not instantly after first fling ofcourse - it could be even after houndreds of fast flings (tested on iPhone 4).

What I do is:

1. In `- tableView: targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath: toProposedIndexPath:` I’m changing the `proposedDestinationIndexPath` taking into account the calculated velocity based on time change between invocations of this method and change in cell’s `origin.y` and setting the flag that cell is moving.
2. `reloadData` in `- tableView: didEndDisplayingCell: forRowAtIndexPath:` and unset the `isMoving` flag
3. Update model and unset the `isMoving` flag

App is crashing somewhere between a start of the fling (`- tableView: targetIndexPathForMoveFromRowAtIndexPath: toProposedIndexPath:`) and landing in a destination (`- tableView:moveRowAtIndexPath: toIndexPath:`).

I suspect that its because I'm disrupting somehow internal structure of table view, but don’t really understand what exactly is going on, and how to fix it. The reason is:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9 beyond bounds [0 .. 8]'

In fact at the moment when crashes we could have possibly 11 visible cells, but only 8 of those are visible at the moment (attached screenshot):
[image: Sample app in the moment of crash]

Any ideas how to make it stable?

Comment: Datasource code would be helpful.

Comment: https://github.com/Czajnikowski/FlingUX/blob/master/FlingUX/FUXViewController.m